# Access control for container as a service

Tags: security, docker, multi-tenant

In case i have a container as a service platform serving containers to different tenants' users. And a single host can be hosting containers of different tenants. how can i allow access over HTTP while making sure that a user can access only his tenant's containers?
Does Kubernetes solve that? Is there a more lightweight solution?

Answer (score 1):

[DCHQ](https://www.dchq.io/) absolutely solves this problem.